# How can I isolate internal circuit from external power from L298N?

Tags: diodes, flyback, backup

I have a small simple circuit where an ESP32 runs an L298N driver for a single DC motor (not a stepper.)  The run and direction are controlled by a simple web page with two buttons.  The code works fine, no issues there.  I would like to have a second set of physical switches for the router / internet outages.  The L298N module has "flyback diodes" as shown in the attached layout.  These are labeled M7F which should be [these](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/4845/DS_3372_M7F.pdf).

[image: Module]

Given this is a cheap knock off driver module, it is probably safe to assume the diodes are as well.  Do I need a Schottky on the 12V and 5V (VCC, VS) to prevent reverse current if/when the flyback fails?  Note the power is supplied from the main of my house via power supply.  I am hoping the power supply has protections built in, but again, not the highest quality component.

If so, can they be placed inline on the Out1 and Out2 or should they be after the module and before the power supply?

Note: It is entirely possible I have gone full Nancy here, if so, it's what it is.

Comment: The output of the 7805 should be connected directly to the L298 +5V terminal, with the  bottom of C1 and R1/D1 both connected to Ground.  Your drawing shows C1 and R1/D1 in series with between th 7805 output and the L298 +5 V terminal - that won't work.

Comment: 5 V on pin 4 and 12 V on pin 9 is not useful. Did you really connect it that way?

Comment: The diagram is from the data sheet for the module.  I have not wired it up yet.  I am trying to determine if I need to add another layer of schottkys .

Comment: It is not clear to me, where these additional switches would be placed.